# Having error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONSTRAINT'."

Tags: mysql, database

```
Create Table OrderDetails
(
    OrderID smallint,
    ProductID smallint,
    UnitPrice money,
    Quantity smallint,
    Discount decimal,

    CONSTRAINT OrderDetails_OID_PID_pk PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, ProductID)
);
```

Comment: Where did you find `money` in the documentation?

Comment: The error is not near constraint, but near "Quantity". See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0105d2516ddfcda64148d160f9970de8. The problem is that the data type `money` does not exist in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

**UnitPrice *money*,** in invalid.

Use the datatypes **Decimal** or **Numeric** for representing currency